# Как в Symphony 3 подключить свою библиотеку?

Tags: php, autoload

Я занимаюсь разработкой библиотеки для работы с файлами и хочу подключить ее к проекту на Symphony 3. Но не знаю как это правильно сделать, а костыли городить не хочу. У библиотеки имеется свое пространство имен.

Comment: что значит своя библиотека? composer-пакет? или свой symfony-bundle?

Comment: Нет это не пакет, скорее что-то ближе к symfony-bundle. Я до конца ещё не  разобрался с symfony-bundle. Насколько я понял это библиотеки написанные для симфони которые могут иметь свои контроллеры, модели, роуты и тд, но моя библиотека ничего подобного не должна содержать. Вот я и думаю разумно ее как бандл подключать?

Comment: хорошо, а как вы ее сейчас подключаете?